# MVC3 Custom AuthorizeAttribute : how to pass in an object from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

I have an object that contains all login data, that's in my controller (it was programmed before switching to MVC3).

I'm trying to add authorization to the site, so so far I have:

```
public LoginObject MyLoginObject
{
   get;
   set;
}

[CustomAuthorization()]
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}
```

and

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
    return true;
    //should be return myLoginObject.IsLoggedIn;
   }
}
```

Is there anyway to pass MyLoginObject into the AuthorizeAttribute class? If not could I at least pass in a boolean from the object that specifies if the user is authorized or not?

**Edit:** My solution based on Zonnenberg's advice.

```
public class LoginObject : IPrincipal // Now extends IPrincipal 
{
   ... //old code
   private class IdentityImpl : IIdentity
{
  public string AuthenticationType
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public bool IsAuthenticated
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public IIdentity Identity
{
  get { return new IdentityImpl { AuthenticationType = "Custom Authentication", IsAuthenticated = this.IsLoggedIn, Name = this.Id}; }
}
}
```

Then I moved the instantiation of loginobject into CustomAuthorization

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
  // ... Set up LoginObject
    filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User = myLoginObject;

  base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

So now logging in, is done inside the authorization, and I can call User to access the login from the controller.

Comment: Can't you access the controller context via the HTTP context?

Comment: What's this `Login` object that you are talking about? Where does it come from? How is this action requested? What is contained in the request? You just talked about *my login object* which I am afraid doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The login object is a custom created class. Its an object created to refer to an admin user's login credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check wheter the user is logged in by using *httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated*.

To store more information you could use the *httpContext.User* object. You can write your own implementation of *IPrincipal* and *IIdentity* to store all kinds of login information.

Other option is to store login info in the Session.

Answer (score 0):

How is your LoginObject instantiated?

If it's instantiated via a service or repository (ex. `MyLoginObject = loginService.GetLogin()` then you can move this call into the CustomAuthorization attribute.

If the logic is within the controller itself then this should be refactored into a service or repository depending on you solution architecture so that you can do the above.