# MVC 4 - RoleProvider to manage authenticated users permissions with different scopes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider, role-base-authorization

Here is my problem with my MVC 4 Internet project using Forms Authentication.
Lets say i have hotels and i want the authorized users accessing each under different roles.

So the user logs in. Then from a dropdownlist selects the target Hotel and the application´s security responds accordingly.

I would need something like [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] but only in that hotel scope.

My first aproach was inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute and override AuthorizeCore like is shown in this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037213/asp-net-mvc-attribute-to-only-let-user-edit-his-her-own-content)

From there I could get the HttpContext.Session["HotelId"] and query a UserRolesInHotel table. That said, I should have my own roles table with a structure similiar to UserId, RoleId, HotelId. So SimpleRolePrivider comes short to this task and i would be forced to create a CustomeRoleProvider. RoleProvider Methods don´t handle extra params as I need like HotelId when adding a new role to a user.

For clarification:

1. User A logs in with user/password ->OK (SimpleMembershipProvider)
2. Authenticated User A selects Hotel 1 -> User A is an "Administrator" for Hotel 1.
3. Authenticated User A change to Hotel 2 -> User A is a "User" in Hotel 2

I can have any number of hotels.

1. User A -> Hotel 1 -> { "Administrator", "User"}
2. User A -> Hotel 2 -> { "User" }
3. User A -> Hotel 3 -> { "Owner" }
4. User A -> Hotel 4 -> { "Administrator" }

The list of roles is always the same.

I´ve been struggling with this implementation for a couple of days and i couldn´t come up with a pratical solution.
Any thougths would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I am finding myself dealing with the same problem you had =/. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

- Added a DefaultBuildingId to the user profile.
- Then I created a CustomRoleProvider and overrided GetRolesForUser method like this

  ```
  public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userName)
  {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
      {
          var user = _userRepository.GetByName(userName);

          if (!user.IsActive)
          {
              throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("some message {0}", userName));
          }

          if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BuildingId"] == null)
          {
              var building = _buildingRepository.Get(user.DefaultBuildingId);
              if (building == null)
              {
                  throw new ApplicationException("error message");
              }

              HttpContext.Current.Session["BuildingId"] = building.BuildingId;
          }

          int buildingId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["BuildingId"]);
          return _userRepository.GetRolesForUserInBuilding(user.UserId, buildingId).ToArray();
      }

      throw new ApplicationException("error message.");
  }
  ```

  - Added a custom AuthorizeAttribute

    ```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
    var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    if (!authorized)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var repo = UnityManager.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
    var buildingId = (int)httpContext.Session["BuildingId"];
    var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    var user = repo.GetByName(userName);
    var userRolesInBuilding = repo.GetRolesForUserInBuilding(user.UserId, buildingId);

    foreach (var role in Roles.Split(','))
    {
        if (userRolesInBuilding.Contains(role.Trim()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
    ```

    }
  - And finally this is how to use it at controller or action level.

    [BuildingAthorize(Roles = "Administrators")]

I also added a ddl to the layout to let the user change the building and set the new BuildingId overriding the value at the session/db. This way a user can work in different Hotels during the same session and only access areas and functionality he has for that particular hotel.