# MVC 4 - Ensure that user can edit only own data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'v created MVC 4 Photo Sharing application and want to ensure that logged user can edit only his own data. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037213/asp-net-mvc-attribute-to-only-let-user-edit-his-her-own-content#) solution but didn't fully understand it (what is **unit** or if it is the context object how it is involved in AuthorizeCore method). So, I would like someone to offer to me a solution on my example.

Model class:

```
public class Photo
        {
            public int PhotoID { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            .
            .
            .
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }
```

Data Context:

```
    public class PSContext : DbContext, IPSContext
        {
            public PSContext()
            ...
            Photo IPSContext.FindPhotoById(int ID)
                {
                    return Set<Photo>().Find(ID);
                }
        }
```

I would like to create custom AuthorizeAttribute and check if logged user created triggered photo. I dont know how to get triggered object in AuthorizeCore method.

Comment: You must be storing userID of `loggedInUser`.
So you can check if loggedInUser's `userId` doesn't match with the photo record then disable/hide the edit option.

Comment: @Manoz That was the question, how to get Photo object in custom AuthorizeAttribute class. I know how to get logged user id but don't know how to get UserName from Photo object (suppose it should be done using PSContext).

Comment: `AuthorizeAttribute` is the wrong place for this logic. Object-level permissions inherently requires knowledge of the object and how to query it it, which `AuthorizeAttribute` should *not* have. Do the check in the controller, either directly in the action or via a helper method.

Comment: @Chris I thought so first time I faced the problem but I found few posts on Stackoverflow saying that the best place is AuthorizeAttribute. Controller wouldn't be the right place because of caching. I don't know now what to think.

Comment: Caching is not an issue. You can vary on custom, and then use the username as a custom string. The reason not to use `AuthorizeAttribute` for this kind of stuff is introducing a dependency on your context. You can't inject your context into `AuthorizeAttribute`, so you're forced to new up an instance inside, which means you've then got multiple instances of your context per request, which is a huge no-no. It's the *job* of the controller to query the database, so that's where that logic should go.

Comment: Just so I'm not misunderstood, the actual act of querying should occur in the controller, but you're still free, and encouraged, to abstract away the actual querying logic into a repository/service/helper class, etc.

Comment: All right than, that is easier way, I 'm gonna do on that way. Thank you.