# How can I store information while resolving c# attributes in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, attributes

I am writing an MVC application where the access authorization depends on three things: users, business objects, and permission on the business objects. Access to a controller action requires that the user have an appropriate permission on at least one business object, but once there I need the list of business objects.

For instance, to edit a Merchant the User needs the 'edit' Permission for that Merchant. The User must not be able to edit a Merchant that the User has not been granted permission to edit.

I understand how to model this in the database. In the controller I have many places where I need to authorize the user, then follow up with retrieving the list of Merchants the User has permission to modify. These are almost the same query, even.

I'm already planning to extend AuthorizeAttribute to verify (for example) that the User has permission to modify at least one Merchant. Rather than having two separate calls to the database, one of which is handled implicitly by being part of the authorization system and one explicitly inside the method, is there a good way to retrieve the list of Merchants the user is allowed to manipulate and store that so I can access it inside the member?

That is, instead of

```
[AuthorizeAction("edit-merchant")] // this queries database
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  List<Merchant> merchants = data.GetMerchantList(User, "edit-merchant"); // queries database
  // do stuff, return result
}
```

how can I reasonably do something like

```
[AuthorizeAction("edit-merchant")] // this queries database
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  List<Merchant> merchants = cache.GetMerchantList(); // gets cached value
  // do stuff, return result
}
```

Comment: if you're using EF, as long as your context remains in scope (not disposed) `DbContext` maintains state information (first-level caching). You can read more about first- and second-level caching here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx   Of course, if you're not using EF this doesn't apply (but perhaps tell us what you are using)

Comment: Rather than making 2 calls (one in your attribute and one in the method itself), why not just do all the checks inside the method?

Comment: @Juventus18 we're not using EF. It seems brittle when working with Oracle, and the team is not happy with how many hoops we're jumping through for something that should be easy and doesn't work reliably for us.

Comment: @StephenMuecke we want to leverage the authentication/authorization mechanism provided by the framework. As best we can tell, that means adding the permission lookup to the attribute code.

Comment: An `AuthorizeAttribute` is not the place to be querying your database. Suggest you read the comments in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994312/mvc-4-ensure-that-user-can-edit-only-own-data)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the ``AuthorizeAttribute`` already does query the/a database, if you're doing role-based security. I agree that it's a bad place for most database queries, but "does the user have this permission?" and "for what Merchants does the user have this permission?" are so similar I wonder if it's not better to ask the second question in place of the first.

Comment: On the other hand, I do have other queries to ask in setting up the form, so it doesn't really save me anything to try to do it this way. I still need to see if the user has the permission at all, but if common idiom is to do the rest in-method, that's how I'll do it.